# What is ElasticSearch and how can it be used?

Tags: search

I am really quite new to this whole world but I keep hearing lots of talk about ElasticSearch and Kibana.

I have been to their website but would just like a really simple, plain English explanation of how it can be used.

Questions I have in mind are;

- Is it part of the Apache foundation?
- Where does the software sit? Would it form part of an Hadoop ecosystem?
- When would I use it?
- What skills do I need in order to use it?

Bit of a general question i know but something which might be useful for other people too I feel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to the questions above are as follows:

- Q. Is it part of the Apache foundation

  A. Quite simply. No. Elastic is Open Source but not part of the Apache foundation
- Q. Where does the software sit? Would it form part of an Hadoop ecosystem

  A. Elastic is entirely separate from Hadoop and requires its own cluster of machines in order to operate. The data is distributed across this cluster, as in Hadoop however the data is indexed for quick retrieval. There is then a front end visualization and analysis tool called Kibana that can be used to interrogate the data and to write queries
- Q. When would I use it?

  A. When you have a large dataset that you want to query very quickly
- Q. What skills do I need in order to use it?

  A. You will need to be able to write Elastic queries. An SQL-like query language